# A loop function for an exponential multiple by a continuous multiplication function in R

Tags: r, function, loops, package

I try to calculate values from the function:

[image]
And the loop function I write so far is:

However, even though it can run, but when I apply this function to my data, there is an error says "Error : unused argument (.)" Maybe because  `y[q,k] <- ((3+0.01*(q-1))^(-(1:k)))*sum(cumprod(px[1:k]))` is wrong? But it looks like the equation I want. Anyone know how can I fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
Y <- function(x){
  k <- 50-x
  Cset <- seq(0,0.2,0.01)
  y <- matrix(length(Cset)*k,ncol = k)
  for(C in seq_along(Cset)){
    for(s in 1:k){
      y[C,s] <- sum((3+C)^(-s)*cumprod(data$Bx[1:s]))
    }
  }
  y
}

Y(x=30)
```

And the error shows

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, C, s, value = sum((3 + C)^(-s) * cumprod(data$px[1:s]))) : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: Try `Y(x = 30) `

Comment: Thank you for response. But, not really, there is some mistake in my loop itself. :(

Comment: I got a mistake about `px` also. You should check that!

Comment: Yep, that should be Bx, but still does not work.

Comment: You have many places that variable names collide within function scope, you should avoid that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
Y <- function(x){
  k <- 50-x
  Cset <- seq(0,0.2,0.01)
  y <- matrix(length(Cset)*k,ncol = k)
  for(C in seq_along(Cset)){
    for(s in 1:k){
      y[C,s] <- (3+C)^(-s)*sum(cumprod(Bx[1:s]))
    }
  }
  y
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping again!!! Yep, still not work. :(

Comment: @ScarlettZhao I updated my answer so please check it out

Comment: Yep, that looks so good. And it's so wired, when I apply to data, it keep saying "Error in Y(., x = 30) : unused argument (.)"

Comment: @ScarlettZhao I have no clue how it work with pipes. To test the function itself, you'd better set parameters a global variable and then run the function `Y`.

Comment: When I apply the function to the data, is there any other step I need to do? Like, how can I link the data (which contain the Bx value) to the function? So that to calculate the values

Comment: @ScarlettZhao Your function accepts only single argument `x`. Maybe you need to define the function to enable it to read the data first (sorry that I had no experience with pipes)

Comment: Is there any way to enable the function to read the data first without using pipe?

Comment: @ScarlettZhao You can make it as global variable